# Pass component as children to other component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where I am trying to pass children to it but they are not getting displayed correctly. I am passing a `<p>{tweet}</p>` and a component. The tweet is getting displayed but the other component is not getting displayed.

```
<PostContent id={id}
        name={name}
        image={image}
        creatorId={creatorId}
        currUserId= {currUserId}
        likedBy={likedBy}
        retweetedBy={retweetedBy}>
      <>
      <p>{tweet}</p>
      <PostContentStats id={id} 
        creatorId={creatorId} currUserId={currUserId}
        likedBy={likedBy} retweetedBy={retweetedBy} />
      </>
</PostContent>
```

```
const PostContent = ({id,name,image,creatorId,currUserId,likedBy,retweetedBy,children}) => {
      return (
    <article className="border-b-2 b" key={id}>
      <Image className='rounded-full ' src={image} width={45} height={45}/>      
      <div className='w-full'>
          <div className='flex'>
            <h4 className='font-bold cursor-pointer'>{name}</h4>
            <h5 className='ml-2 text-slate-500'>{'@__'+name}</h5>
          </div>
          {children}
      </div>
    </article>
  )
}
```

PostContentStats is not getting displayed.

PostContentStats

```
const PostContentStats = ({id,creatorId,currUserId,likedBy,retweetedBy}) => {

  console.log(id,creatorId,currUserId,likedBy,retweetedBy)
  
    const [deletePost]=useDeletePostMutation();
    
    return (
        <div className='flex justify-around mt-3'>
          <FiMessageCircle size={20} className='mr-2 cursor-pointer hover:text-slate-400'/>
          <LikedPostsStats likedBy={likedBy} currUserId={currUserId} id={id}/>
          {creatorId!==currUserId &&
            <RetweetedPostsStats retweetedBy={retweetedBy} currUserId={currUserId} id={id}/>}
          {creatorId===currUserId && 
            <AiOutlineDelete size={20} className='mr-2 cursor-pointer hover:text-slate-400' 
            onClick={()=>{console.log(id); deletePost(id)}}/>}
        </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: How does `PostContentStats` looks like? Also you can't use the same `id` on multiple elements.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski no

Comment: @Vucko it's the post id. I need it to query the database